# Custom TagHelper does not work in a ASP.NET Web Project (.Net 5)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a custom TagHelper like described in the Docs: [A minimal Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-5.0#a-minimal-tag-helper)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

namespace MyTagHelpers.TagHelpers
{
    public class EmailTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.TagName = "a";    // Replaces <email> with <a> tag
        }
    }
}
```

I add my EmailTagHelper in `_ViewImports.cshtml`:

```
@addTagHelper *, MyTagHelpers
```

And use it on the Razor Page

```
<email></email>
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Project has `Assembly Name` set to `MyProject`.

File `MyProject.csproj`

```
 <PropertyGroup>
        <AssemblyName>MyProject</AssemblyName>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

So, the generated assembly will have file name `MyProject.dll`

To make my `EmailTagHelper` work I need to add it with the right Assembly Name:

```
@addTagHelper *, MyProject
```

It works, despite the parent namespace of my `EmailTagHelper` is still the same `MyTagHelpers`.

Comment: why? I face same problem. your namespace is `MyTagHelpers.TagHelpers` but you cannot use `@addTaghelper *, MyTagHelpers.TagHelpers` ? can not use `@addTaghelper * MyProject.TagHelpers` ?